# Get Duplicate records from a table on combination of Multiple Columns and show 'Y' for Duplicate and 'N' for Single records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I need to find duplicate records from a table on combination of Multiple Columns and show 'Y' for duplicate records along with other columns in a gridView.

To Illustrate :

```
Table A:
ID, Col1 ,    Col2,    Col3 , Col4,   Col5,    Col6,   Col7,   Col8,  Col9 
1,  AVal1,    AVal2,   AVal3, AVal4,   AVal5,  AVal6,  AVal7,  AVal8, AVal9
2,  AVal10,   AVal11,  AVal3, AVal4,   AVal5,  AVal6,  AVal12,  AVal13, AVal14
3,  AVal15,   AVal15,  AVal3, AVal4,   AVal5,  AVal6,  AVal16,  AVal17, AVal18

Table B
ID, Col1, Col2, Col3
```

I need to identify the Duplicate Records from **Table A On the Combination of (Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6)**

And When I select the records from Table A, I should get Duplicate 'N' for RowID 1 and 'Y' for RowID 2 & 3.

```
Select A.Col1,A.Col3, A.Col4, A.Col6, 'Y / N' AS [Duplicate], B.Col2
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
    ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I Tried using GroupBy and Partition, but I have other columns also to be selected whihc cannot be used in GroupBy Clause.

Thanks in Advance
:)

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK`? You *do* understanding the (significant) implications of using such a query hint, correct?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a "record"? SQL Server doesn't have "records", it has a rows and columns, and a single column in a single row has a value. Does "record" mean where the entire row is the same? Perhaps when 1 column has the same values (in every row) as another column?

Comment: @Larnu : Record means a row from a table

Comment: Also SQL Server 2008 reached end of life over a year ago now; you should really be looking at upgrade paths ASAP, if you aren't already. (Removing `NOLOCK` from your question doesn't answer the question of *why* you're using it in the first place either).

Comment: None of those rows are identical, so there are no duplicates. They, at least, all have different values for `ID`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col7`, `Col8`, and `Col9`.

Comment: Row1,2,3 are Duplicate for the Combination of (Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6) - so there are duplicates

Comment: Rows that have some columns the same, and not others, are *not* duplicates, @Mufaddal. A duplicate is where *everything* is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by col3, col4, col5, col6 order by col1) = 1
             then 'N' else 'Y'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: This solution is simple and efficient - works like a charm. Thanks